# Why AWS Bucket Policy NotPrincipal with specific user doesn't work with aws client when no profile is specified?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-iam

I have this AWS S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
           "Sid": "OnlyS3AdminCanPerformOperationPolicy",
           "Effect": "Deny",
           "NotPrincipal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/s3-admin"
           },
           "Action": [
               "s3:*"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
               "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Side note: IAM s3-admin user has AdministratorAccess policy attached.

At first I though the bucket policy didn't worked. It was probably because of the way I tested the operation.

```
aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket-name/file.csv 

Caused:
delete failed: s3://test-cb-delete/buckets.csv An error occurred (AccessDenied)
```

but I if used --profile default as per

```
aws s3 --profile default rm s3://my-bucket-name/file.csv
```

It worked.

I verified and only have one set of credentials configured for the aws client. Also, I am able to list the content of the bucket even when I don't use the --profile default argument.

Why is the aws client behaving that way?

Comment: Don't use your root account to access AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#lock-away-credentials

Comment: I understand that. I also never want to perform any action on this bucket. I want to only allow a specific user to perform actions. root could be an option since it is a last resort case. I would really prefer some specific iam user...

Comment: I created an IAM user, gave it `AdministratorAccess`, created a bucket and gave it the above policy (changing bucket name) and it seems to work just fine. The user was able to delete an object in the bucket. Since it is not working for you, can you provide more information? For example, what command did you use that returned Access Denied? Can s3-admin list the contents of the bucket, upload, etc?

Comment: Your policy seems to be valid and correct. I tested it and it worked as planned. Any chance that you are not supplying the credentials that you think you are, or that the policy has not actually been applied as shown?

Comment: I configured aws-cli with s3-admin acces key. Then called: aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket-name/file.csv

Result: delete failed: s3://test-cb-delete/buckets.csv An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied

Comment: For some reason, it seams to work if i add --profile default.
But, I can still list objects inside bucket with no --profile default... and I only  have one set of credential in cache....

Comment: I edited the question to properly reflect the situation.

Comment: AWS SDKs can get credentials from other places besides the --profile option (that reads from ~/.aws/credentials). For example, environment variables or the metadata service (if running on EC2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [credential precedence provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence) and use that to determine what is different about the two credentials you're authenticating as.

STS has a handly API that tells you who you are. It's similar to the UNIX-like command `whoami`, except for AWS Principals. **To see which credential is which, do this:**

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
aws sts --profile default get-caller-identity
```